# How to include spaces in file names in GForth (GNU Forth)?

Tags: windows, macos, unix, forth, gforth

When I tried including a file on Unix (and Windows) it won't work when it includes spaces. For example, these won't work:

```
include ~/Space Folder/test.fs
include ~/Space\ Folder/test.fs
include "~/Space Folder/test.fs"
include "~/Space\ Folder/test.fs"
include C:\Users\Lim Ding Wen\test.fs
include C:\Users\Lim/ Ding/ Wen\test.fs
include "C:\Users\Lim Ding Wen\test.fs"
```

So.. is there a way to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing the `~` with the path to home directory.  Its the shell that performs variable expansions.

Comment: @devnull works on Unix but not on Windows.

Comment: Did you try escaping \ on Windows, i.e. using \\?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `included` word :

```
s" My File With Spaces.fs" included
```

Tilde expansion will probably not work (haven't tested). If you do not specify an absolute path, then the file needs to be in the `GFORTHPATH`